# ngRoute: URL changes, but the view stays the same

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I don't really know what I'm doing wrong, because the URL changes, but the view stays the same.

**app.js**:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
'ngRoute',
'ui.bootstrap',
'ui.bootstrap-slider',
'angularFileUpload',
'ngTouch',
'ngAnimate',
'r'
]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/data', {
        templateUrl: 'html/data/data.html',
        controller: 'RController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        templateUrl: 'html/start/start.html'
    });
}]);
```

**index.jade**:

```
doctype html
html(ng-app='app')
meta(charset='utf-8')
head
    title i-CoDa
    link(rel='shortcut icon', href='./img/icon.ico')
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="./css/main.css")
body(ng-controller='RController')
    div#navigation.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top(role='navigation')
        div.container
            div.navbar-header
                button.navbar-toggle.navbar-collapse(aria-expanded='false')
                    span.sr-only Toggle navigation
                    span.icon-bar
                    span.icon-bar
                    span.icon-bar
                a.navbar-brand(href='./index.html')
                    img#logo(src="./img/logo.svg", alt="i-CoDa Logo")
            div.collapse.navbar-collapse.navbar-right
                ng-include(src="'./html/navbar/navbar.html'")
    div#main
        div(ng-view)
    footer.container.col-lg-12

    script(src="./js/dependencies.js")
    script(src="./js/bundle.js")
```

**navbar.jade**:

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav
 li.active
    a(href='#/start.html') Start Page
 li.active
    a(href='#/data.html') Data
```

The structure of my project looks like this:

```
|
|_server.R
|_www
  |___html
  |___css
  |___js
  |___index.html
```

I also looked at similar posts and tried everything, but it didn't work.
Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: why do you have `a(href='#/start.html')`and not `a(href='#/start')` ?

Comment: that was an error of mine, but it is changed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it in the wrong way. The `RController` that you are set it on the body is presenting for all of the content inside the body regardless whatever router you will make, while it should be set for the `/data` route only.

Removing it from the body, or, just set it to another controller such as `MasterController` (you also have to create it).

Then you create to a route `/start` (which should have controller + view similars to `/data` route that you currently have)  for the default option, and you define the otherwise option like this

> .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/start' });